# Rewriting Sample Variance using matrices.

Tags: matrices, statistics, regression

I am working on homework currently and am having a difficult time with a specific question dealing with rewriting sample variance. The question is as follows:

Suppose $y_1, ..., y_n$ follow distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$. Let $\textbf y=[y_1, ... ,y_n]'$, and let $\overline{y_.} = \frac{1}{n} \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}y_i$. Show that $s^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y_.})^{2}$ can be written as $\textbf{y'By}$ for some matrix $\textbf B$. Find matrix $\textbf B$.

I've tried to see about just manipulating the given $s^2$ formula to get it into a form that might look useful, and I've tried working backwards from $\textbf{y'By}$ to expand some general form that gets close to the given $s^2$ formula, but I feel like I'm missing something. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You want to rewrite $\frac{1}{n-1} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\overline{y})^{2}$ first as $\frac{1}{n-1} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(y_i-\frac1n \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} y_j \right)^{2}$  and then as $\sum\limits_i\sum\limits_j b_{i,j} y_i y_j$ and find the values of $b_{i,j}$, of which there will be two distinct values one when $i=j$ and one when $i \not=j$

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting from $\frac{1}{n-1}\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(y_i-\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{j=1}^{n}y_j)^{2}$ to the double summation. Is there any hint you could provide? I appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Expand the square to get $$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\overline y)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2-n\overline y^2=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2-\frac1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right)^2$$

Now it is easy to see that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_i^2=(y_1\,\,y_2\,\ldots\,\,y_n)\begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\\\vdots\\ y_n\end{pmatrix}=\boldsymbol y^T\boldsymbol y$$

Similarly, you have

$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i=(1\,\,1\,\ldots\,\,1)\begin{pmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\\\vdots\\ y_n\end{pmatrix}=\boldsymbol 1^T\boldsymbol y=\boldsymbol y^T\boldsymbol 1$$